# TeamViewer don't work with remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

When you start TeamViewer on a computer, even if this computer logs out, you can connect (and enter the credentials).

But if you have started TeamViewer from a remote desktop session, when the computer logs out, TeamViewer closes. You need to log back in via RDP to have TeamViewer reactivated.

I've tried scheduling a task to start TeamViewer, but it doesn't work either. It is a computer that I cannot physically access, I always need to work by remote desktop.

Any ideas to fix this ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set teamviewer to start with windows? They have that option so it will start as soon as the pc turns on. Also set unattended access.

Comment: Yes @Darius, but that would force me to restart the computer and it is not always possible.

Comment: I didn't ask you to restart the computer. If you set Teamviewer to start with Windows - even if you log off - teamviewer will run as a service - whether someone logged on, or not. And by setting Unattended Access - you can teamview directly to the login screen.